# bold the characters in the domain, if it matches the keyword

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I need to bold a the domain part where it matches the keyword.

```
//    keyword: this|example // (pipe is separator)
//    domain:  thisisanexample.com
//    result:  <b>this</b>isan<b>example</b>.com
```

and this code does the trick:

```
function colorDomain(domain, keyword) {
    var keywordSplit = keyword.split('|');
    var colorDomain = domain
    for (let index = 0; index < keywordSplit.length; index++) {

        if (keywordSplit[index].toLowerCase() != '') {
            var current = keywordSplit[index].toLowerCase();
            colorDomain = colorDomain.replace(current, "<b>" + keywordSplit[index].toLowerCase() + "</b>");
        }
    }
    return colorDomain;
}
```

The problem i have is where it try to bold the following data:

```
//    keyword:         say|yes
//    domain:          example-sayes.com
//    result:          example-<b>say</b>es.com
//    expected result: example-<b>sayes</b>.com
```

as you can see, it only bold the first part of the domain, because the 'y' is shared in the 'sayes' domain.

keep in mind that the keyword may contain 4+ conditions as:

```
//    keyword: this|is|somthing|great // now there is shared 's' and shared 'g' and 't'

//    and for a domain like: greathisisomethinghello.com
//    it will produce:       grea<b>th<b>is</b></b>isomethinghello.com
//    expected result:       <b>greathisisomething</b>hello.com
```

and then it gets more complex.

how can i bold the string successfully considering this scenario, a regex pattern would solve this issue?

Comment: What is the expected result for `example-sayes.com`?

Comment: see my edit with expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to generate a "bitmap" first, which is an array that has 0 for each normal char and 1 for each bold one, and then insert tags between the 0's and 1's in the bitmap:

```js
function hilite(str, keywords) {

    // create a bitmap, 0 = normal char, 1 = bold char

    let bits = [...str].fill(0);

    keywords.split('|').forEach(kw => {
        let i = -1;

        while (1) {
            i = str.indexOf(kw, i + 1);
            if (i < 0)
                break;
            bits.fill(1, i, i + kw.length);
        }
    });

    // insert tags between 0/1 and 1/0 in the bitmap

    let res = '',
        prev = 0;

    bits.forEach((b, i) => {
        if (b && !prev) {
            res += '<b>';
        }
        if (!b && prev) {
            res += '</b>';
        }
        res += str[i];
        prev = b;
    });

    if (prev)
        res += '</b>'

    return res;
}

console.log(hilite('thisisanexample.com', 'this|example'))
console.log(hilite('example-sayes.com', 'say|yes'))
console.log(hilite('greathisisomethinghello.com', 'this|is|something|great'))
```

Comment: Thanks, very creative solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array that contains the indexes where the keywords occur in the input, merge the portions that intersect and only then generate the output. Here is an example:

```js
const keywords = 'this|is|something|great';
const input = 'greathisisomethinghello.com';

const indexes = keywords.split('|').reduce((a, c) => {
  let startIndex = input.indexOf(c);
  while (startIndex !== -1) {
    a.push({
      startIndex,
      endIndex: startIndex + c.length
    });
    startIndex = input.indexOf(c, startIndex + 1);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

indexes.sort(({ startIndex: a }, { startIndex: b }) => a - b);

const intersects = (o1, o2) => o1.startIndex <= o2.startIndex && o2.startIndex <= o1.endIndex && o1.endIndex <= o2.endIndex;

const mergedIndexes = indexes.reduce((a, c) => {
  const found = a.find(o => intersects(o, c));
  if (found) {
    found.endIndex = c.endIndex;
  } else {
    a.push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

mergedIndexes.reverse();

const output = mergedIndexes.reduce((a, c) => {
  a = `${a.substring(0, c.startIndex)}<br>${a.substring(c.startIndex, c.endIndex)}</br>${a.substring(c.endIndex)}`;
  return a;
}, input);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var string = "www.google.de";
var search = "gle";

var begin = string.indexOf(search);
var end = begin + search.length;
var result = string.slice(0, begin) + "<b>" + search + "</b>" + string.slice(end);

document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="box">

</div>
```